# Bash Script Doesn't run properly when closing the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

following Bash Script runs properly when I execute the `exit` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$(echo $(who am i) | awk '{print $1" "$5" "$3" "$4}')
formattedUser=$(echo $user | tr -d '()')
finalData=$formattedUser" to "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" "$(date +"%H:%M")
logoutTime=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")":00"
startDate=$(echo $(who am i) | awk '{print $3}')
startDateFinal=$(echo $startDate | tr '-' '/')
startTime=$(echo $(who am i) | awk '{print $4}')
startTimeFinal=$startTime":00"
loginTime=$startDateFinal" "$startTimeFinal

function diff_seconds {
    var1=$(date "+%s" -d "$1");
    var2=$(date "+%s" -d "$2");
    period=$(( $var1 - $var2 ));
}

diff_seconds "$logoutTime" "$loginTime"
periodMins=$(echo $(( period / 60 )))
finalDataToLog=$finalData" "$periodMins
echo $finalDataToLog | tee -a /home/amantha/log-sources/logout.log
chmod 777 /home/amantha/log-sources/logout.log
```

I included above bash script in `.bashrc`.

```
trap /home/amantha/log-sources/logout.sh EXIT
```

You can see the output below.

```
amantha 192.168.1.36 2020-10-05 10:29 to 2020-10-05 10:31 2
```

1st field - user
2nd field - user ip
3rd field - logged in date
4th field - Logged in time
5th filed - "to" word
6th field - logged out date
7th Field - logged out time
8th field - time period

The issue is when i close terminal it doesn't work properly.
Output:

```
to 2020-10-05 10:28 0
```

**My purpose of doing this to determine a user's logged in time and logged out time using ssh**. Do you have any solutuon?
Above one is worked only for exit command. It doesn't work properly when I close terminal or Connection Failiure.

Comment: You might be interested in using the file `~/.bash_logout` This is what `man bash` has to say: _When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists._

Comment: @kvantour : While this for sure makes more sense than using an _EXIT trap_, the OP wants the script to be executed, _when he closes the terminal_. I don't think the bash will process then by doing a graceful logout. Instead it will be killed by some signal.

Comment: @Amantha : For this to work, you need to trap the signal which the terminal is sending to bash, when you close it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve a solved problem.

If you are using RHEL/CENTOS/Fedora. The user's log are stored in:

```
/var/log/wtmp – Logs of last login sessions
/var/run/utmp – Logs of the current login sessions
/var/log/btmp – Logs of the bad login attempts
```

There is also `last` command.
That is well documented [here](https://manpage.me/?q=last).
Here is a good [article](https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-login-history/) solving your problem.

Comment: I support this. A user can easily modify his initfiles to remove this information, even if you place it in `/etc/bashrc`. Using the systems logging interface (using `last`) is much safer.

Comment: I am doing this in ubuntu... **last** command show list of users.. I want to capture last logged-out user and wrtie in to a file... any idea?

Comment: @Amantha Why do you want to log this information if it is already logged. All information can be extracted at any time using the command `last`. This command keeps a full history. See `man last` for details. Example: `last -F -n 2 amantha` will give the last login and logout times of user `amantha`. It will also tell if the user is still logged in or not.

Comment: i want to ship those data to elk... using custom log is very easy to do that task.. i want below fields. 1. user 2. ipaddress 3. logged-in date and time 4. logged-out date and time.. 5. time duration of the session..

Comment: @Amantha, generate your custom log from the `last` command output. use a single `awk` script to process the time differences. `last | awk '{gsub("[()]","");print $1" "$NF}'`